# Update/ install Python scikit learn latest development version in Windows

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn

I am trying to replace/install my Python scikit-learn 0.17.0 with 0.18.dev0 latest development version in Windows, so that I can try out `sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier`.  After reading and trying the advanced user manual here (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/advanced_installation.html#install-bleeding-edge), I am kinda stuck.

```
 pip install -U scikit-learn

 => Still getting 0.17.0 but not 0.18.dev0
```

Could any guru provide step by step guides to install developmental Python 2.70 scikit-learn in windows?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The only way to get the development version is to clone it through git, as follows:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git
```

For Windows, I highly recommend installing Anaconda (https://www.continuum.io/downloads) because it installs all the scientific computing packages that you need for Windows.

Comment: Pip refused to install the develop branch (I already had it installed), uness I included the `--upgrade` flag with my command: `sudo pip install git+https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git#egg=scikit-learn --upgrade`

Answer (score 3):

I have same problem with you. After trying several solutions, I finally get sklearn 0.18 worked by simply type:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git#egg=scikit-learn
```

Answer (score 0):

`conda install scikit-learn`

seems to do the job of updating to the latest version.

you can find the package you are looking for there:

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
```

This is valid if you are using Anaconda, ofc.