# Cannot import sklearn.model_selection in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to import `sklearn.model_selection`. I have tried to reinstall scikit-learn and anaconda, still not working. 
Here is the error msg I got:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-e49df3a70ea4> in <module>()
      4 get_ipython().magic(u'matplotlib inline')
      5 # from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
----> 6 import sklearn.model_selection

/Users/Lu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from ._split import BaseCrossValidator
      2 from ._split import KFold
      3 from ._split import GroupKFold
      4 from ._split import StratifiedKFold
      5 from ._split import TimeSeriesSplit

/Users/Lu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py in <module>()
     34 from ..utils.random import choice
     35 from ..base import _pprint
---> 36 from ..gaussian_process.kernels import Kernel as GPKernel
     37 
     38 __all__ = ['BaseCrossValidator',

/Users/Lu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/gaussian_process/__init__.py in <module>()
     11 """
     12 
---> 13 from .gpr import GaussianProcessRegressor
     14 from .gpc import GaussianProcessClassifier
     15 from . import kernels

/Users/Lu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/gaussian_process/gpr.py in <module>()
     10 import numpy as np
     11 from scipy.linalg import cholesky, cho_solve, solve_triangular
---> 12 from scipy.optimize import fmin_l_bfgs_b
     13 
     14 from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin, clone

/Users/Lu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/__init__.py in <module>()
    232 from .optimize import *
    233 from ._minimize import *
--> 234 from ._root import *
    235 from .minpack import *
    236 from .zeros import *

/Users/Lu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_root.py in <module>()
     17 
     18 from .optimize import MemoizeJac, OptimizeResult, _check_unknown_options
---> 19 from .minpack import _root_hybr, leastsq
     20 from ._spectral import _root_df_sane
     21 from . import nonlin

/Users/Lu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in <module>()
      2 
      3 import warnings
----> 4 from . import _minpack
      5 
      6 import numpy as np

ImportError: cannot import name _minpack
```

Comment: did you think to update `scipy`? How did you reinstall sklearn ? with `conda` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check your scikit-learn version;

```
import sklearn
print(sklearn.__version__)
```

`sklearn.model_selection` is available for version 0.18.1.

What you need to import depends on what you require. For instance, in version 0.18.1, `GridSearchCV` can be imported as

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
```

Whereas in version 0.17.1, the same can be imported as

```
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
```

If you find anything in the new scikit documentation that doesn't work for you in your system, then search the document for the current version you are using. The import path might be different but the overall functionality ought to be the same.

If you don't have any previous projects or code that requires the older version, the better option would be to update your scikit-learn package. As you stated that you use Anaconda, the following post would be useful:

[How to upgrade scikit-learn package in anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33679938/how-to-upgrade-scikit-learn-package-in-anaconda)

Comment: I did: `conda update conda` and `conda install scikit-learn=0.18`, shows `The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:    numpy:        1.11.2-py27_0     
    scikit-learn: 0.18.1-np111py27_0`, then it give the error `CondaOSError: OS error: failed to link (src=u'/Users/Lu/anaconda/pkgs/numpy-1.11.2-py27_0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/compat/__init__.py', dst='/Users/Lu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/compat/__init__.py', type=1, error=OSError(17, 'File exists'))`.

Comment: @Echo: Good, carry on. Try your example again after the install and come back to us and report the outcome.

Comment: I tried `pip uninstall` and `pip install scikit-learn`, shows `Successfully installed scikit-learn-0.18.1`. But In python shows I'm using 0.17.1

Comment: @Echo: (Been there, felt that) You are using Anaconda, right? Then you ought to install from its path (if you have the rights/privileges). I'm guessing you have both Anaconda installation of python alongside with another installation. What is your OS?

Comment: @Echo: Then we are in the same boat. What does `which python` in terminal return to you?

Comment: It gives `/Users/Lu/anaconda/bin/python`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128196/discussion-between-ebe-isaac-and-echo).

Comment: Thanks for the help @ÉbeIsaac. Figured out my problem is although scikit-learn 0.18 is installed, when importing, it still uses 0.17. I used this post to install http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35375413/update-install-python-scikit-learn-latest-development-version-in-windows, and now it is using 0.19.dev, and able to load 0.19 and model_selection

Comment: @Echo Always happy to help.