# ImportError: cannot import name model_selection

Tags: python, importerror, data-science

I am trying to learn data analysis using the iris data set. So I just am copying the already written code for this subject and I get the following error regarding the libraries :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "iris.py", line 6, in <module>
    from sklearn import model_selection
ImportError: cannot import name model_selection
```

And here is how I import this module:
`from sklearn import model_selection`

I am using python 2.7,
What could be the problem?
I suspect there might be a problem with the version!right?or not?

Please don't suggest Anaconda, I am not willing to use it.

Thanks a bunch

Comment: Do you have a file named `sklearn.py` in the current directory?

Comment: Which version of sklearn did you use ?http://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new.html#version-0-18

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot import sklearn.model\_selection in scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40615021/cannot-import-sklearn-model-selection-in-scikit-learn)

Comment: @JohnGordon, No I don't

Comment: @Mr_U4913, I am using sklearn version '0.16.1'

Comment: @Sriram, I don't get to relate my case to the topic you pointed out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### sklearn.model_selection is available for version 0.18 or late version

```
Please update your sklearn by pip or other tools
```

org website
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new.html#version-0-18

Version 0.18

September 28, 2016
Last release with Python 2.6 support
Scikit-learn 0.18 will be the last version of scikit-learn to support Python 2.6. Later versions of scikit-learn will require Python 2.7 or above.
Model Selection Enhancements and API Changes

The model_selection module
The new module sklearn.model_selection, which groups together the functionalities of formerly sklearn.cross_validation, sklearn.grid_search and sklearn.learning_curve, introduces new possibilities such as nested cross-validation and better manipulation of parameter searches with Pandas.
Many things will stay the same but there are some key differences. Read below to know more about the changes.
Data-independent CV splitters enabling nested cross-validation