# Unable to import any model from sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Newbie to Machine Learning and Python. None of the model under sklearn can be imported. It was working few days back. But then I updated anaconda since then facing OS Error issue. Where Am i going wrong?

Thanks in advance

I am using Jupyter Notebook python3.6, Win 10. 
I tried

```
import sklearn
assert sklearn.__version__ >= "0.20"
```

I upgraded all Libraries which exceed mentioned on documentation:
sklearn  0.21.3

numpy  1.16.5

scipy  1.3.1

joblib 0.13.2

I reinstalled Anaconda, Python, remove the root directories under 'User' folder

Also read 
[Cannot import sklearn.model_selection in scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40615021/cannot-import-sklearn-model-selection-in-scikit-learn)

````
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
OSError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-73edc048c06b> in <module>
----> 1 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\__init__.py in 
 <module>
 17 from ._split import check_cv
 18 
---> 19 from ._validation import cross_val_score
 20 from ._validation import cross_val_predict
 21 from ._validation import cross_validate

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in 
<module>
 25 from ..utils.metaestimators import _safe_split
 26 from ..utils._joblib import Parallel, delayed
---> 27 from ..metrics.scorer import check_scoring, 
_check_multimetric_scoring
 28 from ..exceptions import FitFailedWarning
 29 from ._split import check_cv

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\__init__.py in <module>
  5 
  6 
----> 7 from .ranking import auc
  8 from .ranking import average_precision_score
  9 from .ranking import coverage_error

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\ranking.py in <module>
 33 from ..utils.sparsefuncs import count_nonzero
 34 from ..exceptions import UndefinedMetricWarning
---> 35 from ..preprocessing import label_binarize
 36 
 37 from .base import _average_binary_score

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\__init__.py in <module>
  4 """
  5 
----> 6 from ._function_transformer import FunctionTransformer
  7 
  8 from .data import Binarizer

~\Anaconda3\lib\site
packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_function_transformer.py in <module>
  3 from ..base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
  4 from ..utils import check_array
----> 5 from ..utils.testing import assert_allclose_dense_sparse
  6 
  7 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\testing.py in <module>
716 
717 try:
--> 718     import pytest
719 
720     skip_if_32bit = pytest.mark.skipif(_IS_32BIT,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytest.py in <module>
  4 """
  5 from _pytest import __version__
----> 6 from _pytest.assertion import register_assert_rewrite
  7 from _pytest.config import cmdline
  8 from _pytest.config import hookimpl

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\__init__.py in <module>
  5 from typing import Optional
  6 
   7 from _pytest.assertion import rewrite
  8 from _pytest.assertion import truncate
  9 from _pytest.assertion import util

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\rewrite.py in <module>
 24 from _pytest._io.saferepr import saferepr
 25 from _pytest._version import version
---> 26 from _pytest.assertion import util
 27 from _pytest.assertion.util import (  # noqa: F401
 28     format_explanation as _format_explanation,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\util.py in
<module>
  6 from typing import Optional
  7 
----> 8 import _pytest._code
  9 from _pytest import outcomes
 10 from _pytest._io.saferepr import saferepr

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\_code\__init__.py in <module>
  1 """ python inspection/code generation API """
----> 2 from .code import Code  # noqa
  3 from .code import ExceptionInfo  # noqa
  4 from .code import filter_traceback  # noqa
  5 from .code import Frame  # noqa

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\_code\code.py in <module>
 21 
 22 import attr
---> 23 import pluggy
 24 import py
 25 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\__init__.py in <module>
 14 ]
 15 
---> 16 from .manager import PluginManager, PluginValidationError
 17 from .callers import HookCallError
 18 from .hooks import HookspecMarker, HookimplMarker

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py in <module>
  9     from importlib import metadata as importlib_metadata
 10 else:
---> 11     import importlib_metadata
 12 
 13 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py in <module>
545 
546 
--> 547 __version__ = version(__name__)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py in version(distribution_name)
507         "Version" metadata key.
508     """
--> 509     return distribution(distribution_name).version
510 
511 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py in distribution(distribution_name)
480     :return: A ``Distribution`` instance (or subclass thereof).
481     """
--> 482     return Distribution.from_name(distribution_name)
483 
484 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py in from_name(cls, name)
181             context = DistributionFinder.Context(name=name)
182             dists = cls._maybe_bind(resolver, context)
--> 183             dist = next(dists, None)
184             if dist is not None:
185                 return dist

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py in <genexpr>(.0)
423         return itertools.chain.from_iterable(
424             cls._search_path(path, pattern)
--> 425             for path in map(cls._switch_path, paths)
426             )
427 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py in _search_path(cls, root, pattern)
447     @classmethod
448     def _search_path(cls, root, pattern):
--> 449         if not root.is_dir():
450             return ()
451         normalized = pattern.replace('-', '_')

~\Anaconda3\lib\pathlib.py in is_dir(self)
   1356         """
   1357         try:
-> 1358             return S_ISDIR(self.stat().st_mode)
   1359         except OSError as e:
   1360             if not _ignore_error(e):

~\Anaconda3\lib\pathlib.py in stat(self)
   1166         os.stat() does.
   1167         """
-> 1168         return self._accessor.stat(self)
   1169 
   1170     def owner(self):

OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect:
'C:\\Users\\Omkar\\$SPARK_HOME\\python:$SPARK_HOME\\python\\lib\\py4j-VERSION-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH' ```
````